# How to solve simple differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem

$$y' = \frac{1 + y^2}{x};\ y(1)=1;\ x>0$$

by separation of variables.

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?  We will be able to help you more if you post your work.

Comment: @anorton, I fail at integration part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$ and you get $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1+y^2}{x} \implies \frac{dy}{1+y^2} = \frac{dx}{x}$ and integrate both sides. use $y(1) = 1$ to find the value of constant after integration.

Comment: So we integrate both sides from 1 to something? And can you please give an explanation of integrating 1/(1+y^2)?

Comment: No no ... just plain indefinite integration. $\int \frac{dy}{1+y^2} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: Are you sure we're not supposed to integrate from 1 to y or from 1 to x respectfully?

Comment: No ... this is indefinite integration that results in integral constant $C$, and we use that initial condition to find the value of this $C$

Comment: ok, so then I should end up with y=tan(ln(x)+1). Can you confirm?

Comment: $y = \tan \left( \ln x + C \right)$ put $y(1) = 1$, we get $1 = \tan(\ln 1 + C) $ so the latter $1$ you wrote must be $\pi \over 4$

Comment: oh, ok, now I see (I just substituted C with y(1)). Thanks!